# re-express Categorical Field values using R

Tags: r, numeric, levels

I have a dataset with a column called education. The education column has several names. I want to replace those names with numerical number.
Once I am done with that, I go to see the new column in the dataset which gives me NA.

Here is my attempt:

```
library(plyr)                 #Load plyr package 

edu.num <- revalue(x = bank_train$education,replace = 
                     c("illiterate" = 0,
                       "basic.4y" = 4,
                       "basic.6y" = 6,
                       "basic.9y" = 9,
                       "high.school" = 12,
                       "professional.course" = 12,
                       "university.degree" = 16,
                       "unknown" = NA))
bank_train$education_numeric <- as.numeric(levels(edu.num))[edu.num]
```

[image]

Comment: Not the most efficient way but this should work: `bank_train$education_numeric <- sapply(as.character(bank_train$education), switch, "illiterate" = 0, "basic.4y" = 4,
"basic.6y" = 6,
"basic.9y" = 9,
"high.school" = 12,
"professional.course" = 12,
"university.degree" = 16, NA)
`

Comment: Another way:  `reval <- c("illiterate" = 0,
"basic.4y" = 4,
"basic.6y" = 6,
"basic.9y" = 9,
"high.school" = 12,
"professional.course" = 12,
"university.degree" = 16,
"unknown" =NA)
;bank_train$education_numeric <- reval[match(bank_train$education, names(reval))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`revalue` function doesn't returns a factor object, but a character vector.
So `levels(edu.num)` returns "NULL", since `levels` function is adapted to factors.

So you should just modify this last line of the code

```
library(plyr)#Load plyr package 

edu.num <- revalue(x = bank_train$education,replace = 
                 c("illiterate" = 0,
                   "basic.4y" = 4,
                   "basic.6y" = 6,
                   "basic.9y" = 9,
                   "high.school" = 12,
                   "professional.course" = 12,
                   "university.degree" = 16,
                   "unknown" = NA))
bank_train$education_numeric <- as.numeric(edu.num)
```